# Ionic background img on div not loading LOCAL images but loads images from internet urls

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have this div which is loading perfectly image url from the internet but not my local image, very weird:

```
   <div class="col biggest-grid dir-medico-grid" ng-click="showDirMedico()">
          <img src="../img/dirmedico.png" class="img"/>

          <p>DIRECTORIO MÉDICO</p>
        </div>
```

So when I try this it works with no problem:

```
.dir-medico-grid{
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/652/confectionary.png);

}
```

but if I try this:

```
.dir-medico-grid{

  background: url(../www/img/doctors.jpg);
}
```

Now it doesn't work as you can se my path is correct i'm going from ionic.app.scss to doctors.jpg:

[image]

I have tried with `background: url(../www/img/doctors.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed;`, with `'../www/img/doctors.jpg'` and `"../www/img/doctors.jpg"` with `background-image`instead of `background` but nothing seems to work this is very weird.

Comment: Use the full path of the image on the local machine just for testing. Let us know the result.

Comment: Try `background: url('/www/img/doctors.jpg');` https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: @chrisbedoya that didn't work but this works `background: url('../img/doctors.jpg');` I'm perplexed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `img/dirmedico.png` in html

```
<img src="img/dirmedico.png" class="img"/>
```

And for css

```
.dir-medico-grid{

  background: url("../img/doctors.jpg");
}
```

The thing is for html, all templates are rendered on index.html which is in same directory with `img`.